# What's the difference between 重覆 and 重复?

Tags: difference

I had thought 重复 means to repeat something over and over, and only today saw the word 重覆 used in a context where it seems to have the same meaning.

What's the difference between 重覆 and 重复?

Comment: In traditional Chinese, 重複 is preferable to 重覆, though the latter one is also acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

重覆 is traditional whereas 重复 is simplified. There is no difference in pronunciation or meaning.